# Android Facebook SDK - java.lang.NoClassDefDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using official android facebook SDK (downloaded from here: http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

When the program reaches the line Facebook facebook = new Facebook(); i get 
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook".

I created a facebook project from sources downloaded and in my project I added the facebook project in buildpath (in Eclipse right click on my project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Projects -> add projects -> I choosed the facebook project). The project builds ok, I have no errors.

Any suggestions?
Thank you all.

Comment: try doing this.. open facebook project export that as jar file and add that jar file to your project and then run your project

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse right click on the project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add -> Select the Facebook project

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that facebook project is also built before you start your program. Otherwise adding Facebook Project as dependency should have worked fine.